# Inserting data into Junction object

Tags: apex

How would you insert multiple records into the junction object?

I have the following Junction object name (`Associate_Employee__c`)
with the following fields:

```
Employee_Request__c
Employer_Request__c
```

both are master_detail relationship

```
List<Associate_Employee__c> aeList = new List<Associate_Employee__c>();
List<Employee_Request__c> empList = new List<Employee_Request__c>();
List<Employer_Request__c> emplorList = new List<Employer_Request__c>();

Associate_Employee__c pa = new Associate_Employee__c(); 
Employee_Request__c empReq = new Employee_Request__c();
//record 1 
empReq.Project_Name = 'SFDC1'; 
empList.add(empReq);
//record 2
empReq = new Employee_Request__c();
empReq.Project_Name = 'SFDC2'; 
empList.add(empReq);
insert empReq; //INSERT

aeList.Employee_Request__c = empReq.id; // ??? How can I reference? If you got multiple records?
```

same goes with the other object `Employer_Request__c`

Comment: if you have multiple master records then on what basis you will enter records in junction object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an small attempt to retrieved multiple records from insertion and create Junction object records.

Leverage `Database.insert()` method which will return `SaveResult` and has `getId()` method to retrieve Id which has been inserted.

This kind of logic might help you!

```
List<Associate_Employee__c> aeList = new List<Associate_Employee__c>();
List<Employee_Request__c> empList = new List<Employee_Request__c>();
List<Employer_Request__c> emplorList = new List<Employer_Request__c>();


//insert Employee request record
for(integer i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    Employee_Request__c empReq = new Employee_Request__c();
    empReq.Project_Name = 'SFDCempReq' + i; 
    empList.add(empReq);
}
Database.SaveResult[] srEmpList = Database.insert(empList, false);

//insert Employer request record
for(integer i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    Employer_Request__c employerReq = new Employer_Request__c();
    employerReq.Project_Name = 'SFDC2' + i; 
    emplorList.add(employerReq);
}

Database.SaveResult[] srEmployerList = Database.insert(emplorList, false);

//loop through the SaveResults to get the inserted Ids in the loop and prepare junction records.
for (Database.SaveResult srEmp : srEmpList) {
    if (srEmp.isSuccess()) 
    {

        for(Database.SaveResult srEmployer : srEmployerList)
        {
            if(srEmployer.isSuccess())
            {
                Associate_Employee__c assoEmp = new Associate_Employee__c();
                assoEmp.Employee_Request__c =  srEmp.getId();
                assoEmp.Employer_Request__c = srEmployer.getId();
                aeList.add(assoEmp);
            }           
        }
    }    
}
insert aeList;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add each one separately. If you had one `Employer_Request__c` Id to join to many `Employee_Request__c` Ids, it would look something like:

```
List<Associate_Employee__c> associateEmployees = new List<Associate_Employee__c>();
// ...
Employee_Request__c employeeRequest = new Employee_Request(/*data*/);
List<Id> employerRequestIds = ...;
for (Id employerRequestId : employerRequestIds)
{
    associateEmployees.add(new Associate_Employee__c(
        Employee_Request__c = employeeRequest.Id,
        Employer_Request__c = employerRequestId
    ));
}
```

Note that naming a variable `empReq` or `empList` is *very* ambiguous here.

Comment: in the above sample code how do think the best way to get the Ids? `List<Id> employerRequestIds`

Comment: I don't know...you're the one writing the code...you didn't provide that context.

Comment: correct, if you have a single record you get the Id after you insert the Employee_Request but in my question I have comment how would you do if you have multiple records inserting?